# Getting value of Nth text node using jQuery

Tags: jquery

If I want to get the value of a text node using jQuery, how would I do this?

For instance, having the following HTML, how would I get only the value "XYZ-123" without needing to parse out "SID:" using regex:

```
<div id="sid"><strong>SID: </strong> XYZ-123</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `filter()` with a `nodeType` of `Node.TEXT_NODE`:

```
$('#sid').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;
}).text();
```

The above code finds the contents and filters based on the `nodeType`. We are interested only on the text nodes.

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  a = $('#sid').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;
  }).text();
  alert(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sid"><strong>SID: </strong> XYZ-123</div>
```

To know more:

- [jQuery `filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [jQuery `contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/).
- [`Node` class and `nodeType`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType).

Comment: How do I get the Nth node though? Suppose there are more than one text node with a more complicated situation such as `<div id="sid"><strong>SKU: </strong>XYZ-123<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>(10ct)</div>` If I want to get the SKU value and the value in the parenthesis separately, how would that work?

Comment: `$('#sid').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;
}).get(WHICH_NODE_HERE).text();`

Comment: @eComEvo Hope that answers! `:)`

Comment: You rock! Thanks! `\m/`

Comment: @eComEvo Glad it helps... `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use get the contents of div element along with filter function to get text node elements:

```
$('#sid').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3; //get text nodes
}).text();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ubzg05mu/)**